# Jquery Fade in fade out, with pause or delay

Tags: jquery, delayed-execution

If have the following code but i cant get a pause AFTER ever fade in   and fade out:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#signupButtonFlash').each(function (i) {
        // Get the image, set the count and an interval.
        var img = $('.bttn_play');
        img[0].$count = 0;
        img[0].$interval = setInterval(function () {
            // Animate the opacity over .2 seconds
            img.animate({
                opacity: .3
            }, 400, function ()

            {
                // When finished, animate it back to solid.
                img.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 400);

            });

            // Clear the interval once we've reached 1000.
            if (++img[0].$count >= 1000) {
                clearInterval(img[0].$interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: So, you want the animation to execute 1000 times. Is that correct, or a mistake?

Comment: Do you really want to use jQuery just to make a button flash?? If thats the case, your users will slap you with that button. Thats nothing you should do, really..

Comment: I allready use jQuery for the rest of the site !

In the first time i searched for a glow on a button like on the tumbnails in this demo:

http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/shinetime/

But i cant disconnect it from the rest of the script.

So i found a fade in / fade out, and was happy with it, but now i cant make a loop with delay from it. 

(I did put a count=1000 in the interval )

Answer (score 0):

This achieves what you want. You could also use `delay` as suggested by others, but I'd be worried about the interval triggering while the previous animation is still running. This code instead trigger the interval at (e.g.) every 1000 ms and fades in and out every other time, oves 200 ms.

Please note that I've moved the `++`!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#signupButtonFlash').each(function (i) {
        // Get the image, set the count and an interval.
        var img = $('.bttn_play');
        img[0].$count = 0;
        img[0].$interval = setInterval(function () {
            // Animate the opacity over .2 seconds
            if (++img[0].$count % 2) {
              img.animate({opacity: .3}, 200)
            }else{
              img.animate({opacity: 1}, 200)
            }

            // Clear the interval once we've reached 1000.
            if (img[0].$count >= 1000) {
                clearInterval(img[0].$interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be reduced significantly:

```
$.fn.fadeLoop = function()
{
    var that = this;
    $(this).data('fadeTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(that).fadeIn(400,  $(that).fadeLoop);
        });
    }, 2000));
};

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('img.bttn_play').hover(function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('fadeTimer'));
        $(this).stop(true).css('opacity', 1);
    }, $(this).fadeLoop)
    .fadeLoop();
});
```

Working **fiddle available** here: http://jsfiddle.net/BEMSD/89/

Comment: Actually, why are you even looping over #signupButtonFlash? There should only be one matching element if it's an id selector like that. You can just do `$(document).ready(function() { fadeLoop.call($('img.bttn_play')); });` -- Let me know how it goes. :-)

Comment: Thank you ! This worked perfectly !

is there any option to stop the animation if mouse over (hover)

Comment: Sure. I've updated code and the fiddle. On hover over it will set the opacity back to 1 and cancel all animations, then resume. I've also converted it to being a very basic jQuery plugin. Should thirst your appetite ;-)

Comment: Thank you again for your fast responses !

But the updated code doesnt work for me! I think because i load the image as background for my button.

Like this : <a class="bttn_play" href="#" title="#"></a>

Comment: Just change `$('img.bttn_play')` to `$('.bttn_play')`

Comment: thank you..its working super !

only a little thing. When i hover the button. The fade animation is flikkering. Looks like the delay of 2000 changes to 200.  Do you think its conflicting with another jquery code in the page. (imageslider) ??

Comment: You mention you use a background image. Have you tried using regular <img> and see if the flickering still persists/

Comment: I did try it with a <img>..still the same !..it seems that if I hover it more often, the button is fading faster...(maybe we can use mouseover option ?).. thank you

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that shows this strange flickering behaviour?

Comment: hi, i tried but cant even  get a background loaded in a (A class) on Fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/BEMSD/6/

Comment: Here, http://jsfiddle.net/BEMSD/7/ -- looks all fine to me. What browser are you getting the flickering in?

Comment: I also get it on your last fiddle! Im using all the browsers with the same result. Try to hover many times over the image very quickly..

Comment: This isn't very solid code at all. A couple of quick mouseover's and mouseout's and you'll see what I mean. It loses its timing and begins acting buggy.

Comment: @VoidKing thanks for your feedback. I've fixed the timing issues by using a setTimeout and clearTimeout, as the `.delay()` isn't cleared with `.stop()` and there's no way to stop the `.delay()` so setTimeout is better in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't exactly help with your code, but maybe you should look into the the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/), because it sounds like you want to cycle through a bunch of images/content in a slideshow manner with the ability to pause/play.

Comment: No i just want some action (animation) in my button for more attention on the button...